# Python subprocess.Popen not stop when using kill()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to restart a python process, when file changes are made.

**Dir Structure**

```
/root
 |_ test.py
 |_ main.py
```

### main.py

```py
import os
import sys
import shutil
import _thread
import subprocess
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEvent

cwd = os.getcwd()
pj = os.path.join
exists = os.path.exists



class Reloader(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, openProc: subprocess.Popen = None, cmd=""):
        super().__init__()
        self.__cmd = cmd

        self.openProc = openProc if openProc else subprocess.Popen(self.__cmd, cwd=cwd, shell=True)

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(event.src_path)
        if ext[1:] in ["py", "cpp", "c", "h", "hpp"]:
            print("::  CHANGES DETECTED, RELOADING ::")
            print("--changed file '{}'--".format(event.src_path))
            self.killProc()
                
    def killProc(self):
        self.openProc.kill()
    


def getInput():
    global cwd
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    return input("⚡>" + cwd + ">")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        userInput = getInput()
        split = userInput.split(" ")

        print("Starting CMD Command With Reloader...")
        while True:
            try:
                event_handler = Reloader(cmd=split)
                observer = Observer()
                observer.schedule(event_handler, cwd, recursive=True)
                observer.start()
                while event_handler.openProc.poll() is None:    
                    pass
                observer.stop()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
```

### test.py

```py
import time
c = 0
while True:
    c+=1
    print(c)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run that:

```sh
E:\electrocli>py main.py
⚡>E:\electrocli>py test.py
Starting CMD Command With Reloader...
1
2
3
4
::  CHANGES DETECTED, RELOADING ::
--changed file 'E:\electrocli\test.py'--
::  CHANGES DETECTED, RELOADING ::
--changed file 'E:\electrocli\test.py'--
5
1
6
2
7
3
```

This shows that, the older process, whis should be revoked by `subprocess.Popen.kill` has not ended. I want to kill the old process, and start the new one. Is there any way to do that? Or, is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: Can you try to display the PID of the new proc when created and the PID of the proc you try to kill ? Just to make sure that you're killing the good process ?

Comment: Did you try using `openProc.terminate()` instead of `kill()` ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Comment: I tried `openProc.terminate()` also, but no improvements.

Comment: It terminates successfully, if the `shell=True` is removed. What does the `shell=True` do?